# How to search within a two-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, search

I'm trying to learn how to search within a two-dimensional array; for example:

```
array = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,4], [2,5]]
```

I want to know how to search within the array for the arrays that are of the form `[1, y]` and then show what the other `y` numbers are: `[1, 2, 3]`.

If anyone can help me understand how to search only with numbers (as a lot of the examples I found include strings or hashes) and even where to look for the right resources even, that would be helpful.

Comment: This part is not clear: `how to search only with numbers (as a lot of the examples I found include strings or hashes)`. Can you add examples to show what you mean?

Comment: I was given the hint that it would be something like array.each { |i| ... } but don't know how to apply it...I'm sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I meant that I wanted to be able to search for arrays that contain the number 1 (in the [0] position) and return the other paired number.  

In this case, I'd like to be able to search through the whole array looking for the internal arrays that have the first number as 1. In the end, I'd like to find out how many items have the number 1 in the first position and what their corresponding partner numbers are (1, 2, 3). This is assuming that I cannot see the numbers in the arrays in the first place.

Comment: That intention is clear. What is not clear is the part that I cited. After all, you may not have needed to mention that at all.

Comment: @sawa I see, okay, thank you for your feedback, I'm probably not asking properly as I don't have a clear understanding of a lot of things...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby allows you to look into an element by using parentheses in the block argument. `select` and `map` only assign a single block argument, but you can look into the element:

```
array.select{|(x, y)| x == 1}
# => [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

array.select{|(x, y)| x == 1}.map{|(x, y)| y}
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

You can omit the parentheses that correspond to the entire expression between `|...|`:

```
array.select{|x, y| x == 1}
# => [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

array.select{|x, y| x == 1}.map{|x, y| y}
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

As a coding style, it is a custom to mark unused variables as `_`:

```
array.select{|x, _| x == 1}
# => [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

array.select{|x, _| x == 1}.map{|_, y| y}
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me, it's very clear!  Also the _ is nice to know for convention.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) and [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) methods:

```
array = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,4], [2,5]]
#=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 5]]
array.select { |el| el[0] == 1 }
#=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
array.select { |el| el[0] == 1 }.map {|el| el[1] }
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

For more methods on arrays explore [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html).

Comment: Ah, I just learned you can only check one answer!? This answer was clear by the one I ended up checking broke it down even further which made it easier for me to then understand this one.

Comment: @Kumo I absolutely agree with your choice, sawa's answer contains great piece of explanation. Good luck in learning Ruby! You can also upvote the helpful answers if you have enough reputation (don't remember how much it should be exactly)

Comment: You could write `map{|el| el[1]}` as `map(&:last)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I know. I was trying to be as explicit as possible, since OP has just started learning the language. IMO Symbol#to_proc isn't a beginner's stuff :)

Answer (score 5):

If you first select and then map you can use the grep function to to it all in one function:

```
p array.grep ->x{x[0]==1}, &:last #=> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same thing is to use [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) together with [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact). This has the benefit of only requiring one block and a trivial operation, which makes it a bit easier to comprehend.

```
array.map { |a, b| a if b == 1 }
#=> [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil]
array.map { |a, b| a if b == 1 }.compact
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was nice and neat and made sense after I read the above.

Comment: A minor point, but this is actually backward (`array.map { |a,b| b if a==1 }`). There is a problem, however: `array = [[1,2],[1,nil]] #=> [2]`, whereas `=> [2,nil]` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
array.each_with_object([]) { |(x, y), a| a << y if x == 1 }
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```